# Custom Typeface not working on Android 5.0 but works elsewhere

Tags: java, android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, android-custom-view

I am using custom fonts in my app, the thing is, it works on android version less than Lollipop and greater than lolliop but on Lollipop it just goes blank

Please find the code and screenshots attached

**SelectionPage.java**

```
package com.execube.volantis.views;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.execube.volantis.R;
import com.execube.volantis.receiver.customHandler;
import com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView;
import com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.RandomTransitionGenerator;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class SelectionPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mEventsButton;
    private Button mAlertsButton;
    private Button mAboutButton;
    private Button mDirectionsButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.selection_page);

        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);

        Pushbots.sharedInstance().setCustomHandler(customHandler.class);











        mEventsButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.events_button);
        mAboutButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        mAlertsButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.alerts_button);
        mDirectionsButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.directions_button);




            Typeface gothamRoundedMedium= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Medium.ttf");
            mEventsButton.setTypeface(gothamRoundedMedium);
        mAboutButton.setTypeface(gothamRoundedMedium);
        mDirectionsButton.setTypeface(gothamRoundedMedium);
        mAlertsButton.setTypeface(gothamRoundedMedium);





        mEventsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent= new Intent(SelectionPage.this,EventActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        mDirectionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + "12.9021902" + "," + "77.518582" + " (" + "RNS Institute Of Technlogy" + ")";
                Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mAlertsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(SelectionPage.this,AlertsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mAboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(SelectionPage.this,AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The buttons use custom fonts.

**Is there any way to set custom fonts only if android version is not equal to Lollipop?**

**Here's Marshmallow API 23**

[image: **Here's Marshmallow API 23**]

**Here's Lollipop API 21**

[image]

Comment: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/02/help-my-custom-font-does-not-work-on-android-5-0/ may helps you

Answer (score 0):

Define type face in application class.

```
public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
        String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

You then need to overload the few default fonts, for example in an application class:

```
public final class Application extends android.app.Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "MyFontAsset.ttf");
   }
}
```

API 21 Android 5.0 use default theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```